# Django error: local variable 'image' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

I have an error in django code. And here is the Traceback:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\dell\Desktop\BlrCityPolice\fir\views.py" in create_image
  123.         file_type = image.image_file.url.split('.')[-1]

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /fir/2/create_image/
Exception Value: local variable 'image' referenced before assignment:
```

views.py:

```
def create_image(request, evidence_id):
    form = ImageForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    evidence = get_object_or_404(Evidence, pk=evidence_id)
    if form.is_valid():
        evidences_images = evidence.image_set.all()
        for s in evidences_images:
            if s.image_title == form.cleaned_data.get("image_title"):
                context = {
                    'evidence': evidence,
                    'form': form,
                    'error_message': 'You already added that image',
                }
                return render(request, 'fir/create_image.html', context)
                image = form.save(commit=False)
                image.evidence = evidence
                image.image_file = request.FILES['image_file']
        file_type = image.image_file.url.split('.')[-1]
        file_type = file_type.lower()
        if file_type not in IMAGE_FILE_TYPES:
            context = {
                'evidence': evidence,
                'form': form,
                'error_message': 'Image file must be JPG, JPEG, or PNG',
            }
            return render(request, 'fir/create_image.html', context)

        image.save()
        return render(request, 'fir/detail.html', {'evidence': evidence})
    context = {
        'evidence': evidence,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'fir/create_image.html', context)
```

create_image.html:

```
{% extends 'fir/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Add a New Image{% endblock %}
{% block evidences_active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <!-- Left Evidence Info -->
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                        <a href="{% url 'fir:detail' evidence.id %}">
                            {% if evidence.informant_image %}
                                <img src="{{ evidence.informant_image.url }}" class="img-responsive">
                            {% else %}
                                <h3>No image to display</h3>
                            {% endif %}
                        </a>
                    <h1>{{ evidence.crime }} <small>{{ evidence.complaint }}</small></h1>
                    <h2>{{ evidence.informant_name }}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Right Image Info -->
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-9">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="{% url 'fir:detail' evidence.id %}">View All</a></li>
                <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="{% url 'fir:create_image' evidence.id %}">Add New Image</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h3>Add a New Image</h3>
                    {% if error_message %}
                        <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
                    {% endif %}
                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="evidence" value="{{ evidence }}">
                        {% include 'fir/form_template.html' %}
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

form_template.html:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <span class="text-danger small">{{ field.errors }}</span>
        </div>
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="image_title">{{ field.label_tag }}</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">{{ field }}</div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

images.html:

```
{% extends 'fir/base.html' %}
{% block title %}All Images{% endblock %}
{% block images_active %}active{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container-fluid multimedia-container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                <li role="presentation" {% if filter_by == 'all' %}class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{% url 'fir:images' 'all' %}">View All</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <table class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Image Title</th>
                                <th>Informant name</th>
                                <th>Image File</th>
                                <th>Evidence</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for image in image_list %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ image.image_title }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ image.evidence.informant_name }}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a target="_blank" href="{{ image.image_file.url }}">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span>&nbsp; Play
                                            </button>
                                        </a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="{% url 'fir:detail' image.evidence.id %}">
                                            <img src="{{ image.evidence.informant_image.url }}" class="img-responsive" style="width: 20px; float: left; margin-right: 10px;" />
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="{% url 'fir:detail' image.evidence.id %}">{{ image.evidence.crime }}</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The culprit is the following lines -

```
image = form.save(commit=False)
image.evidence = evidence
image.image_file = request.FILES['image_file'
```

You should correct it as following,

```
for s in evidences_images:
  if s.image_title == form.cleaned_data.get("image_title"):
    context = {
        'evidence': evidence,
        'form': form,
        'error_message': 'You already added that image',
    }
    return render(request, 'fir/create_image.html', context)
image = form.save(commit=False)
image.evidence = evidence
image.image_file = request.FILES['image_file']
file_type = image.image_file.url.split('.')[-1]
file_type = file_type.lower()
```

Here you are trying to see if the image title send in the form is already there in db and if its already there, then render a page. But the lines after that is wrong as it will never be called because of the render. Once you correct the context in which it is called, you program should work fine.

Comment: I am not able to understand exactly what you are trying to say,if you could please explain it to me. Thanks.

Comment: Just like image,if I have audio,video etc. in the same manner,will that cause a problem?

Comment: In the above case, image variable assignment will never happen because of the return statement present just before it. Hence by the time control reaches `file_type = image.image_file.url.split('.')[-1]`, it will throw the above error.